# map.pause() stopping LocationService with 10.2 SDK

Tags: arcgis-android

I have an app in which I want the LocationService to remain running even if onPause() is called. I have a service running in the foreground with a handler & broadcast receiver that is bound to an activity. The service/activity work together to updates a trackline at an X time interval, both on the map & in a SQLLITE database on the device.

When I call map.pause() in the onPause() method, the locationservice stops listening for location change until I unpause the map again in onResume().

I initialize the LocationService using map.getlocationservice(), so it makes sense that it would stop the LocationService, but I don't want this to happen.

Is there a work around for this? Or perhaps something I'm not understanding correctly?

cross post: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/99435-map.pause()-stopping-LocationService-with-10.2-SDK

Answer (score 1):

I was creating my LocationListener through the LocationService, which came from the map object. Of course the LocationListener would be pausing when I pause the map.

Solution: I moved my LocationListener to the Service & am now broadcasting location updates back to the map activity.